# terraform import aws_backup_selection error unexpected ID format

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-backup, terraform-import

I am importing aws_backup_selection resource but I receive an error:

```
Error: unexpected format of ID ("56XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"), expected <plan-id>|<selection-id>
```

I am importing the resource with the following command:

```
terraform import aws_backup_selection.my_backup_selection 56XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX|1eXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

According to the official [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/backup_selection#import) this is how you import this kind of records:

```
$ terraform import aws_backup_selection.example plan-id|selection-id
```

The plan-id and selection-id provided values are correct.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am following the guide. I even tried something like this which I know makes no sense.

```
terraform import aws_backup_selection.my_backup_selection 56XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX | 1eXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

```
terraform import aws_backup_selection.my_backup_selection <56XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX>|<1eXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX>
```

```
terraform import aws_backup_selection.my_backup_selection "56XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"|"1eXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Answer (score 1):

terraform import "name_of_object" name_of_resource
like this

```
terraform import "aws_backup_selection.example" "1fa13336-32af-4234-a562-71f5fe4c852b|e654d6d9-cef1-3bad-bec5-cb222adc22a9"
```

to get "name_of_object" you can run terraform plan and find it.
Do no forget "" everywhere and check roles. Make sure that role that you use has correct assume settings.
see
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGcC0.png)

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is not related to the question. Please make sure you read the question carefully and then post your answer.

Comment: sorry, but I found time and tested it. And added updated example + screenshot.

Comment: Great! Make sure you remove the real resource IDs from the command as well. Also, I would suggest you add the output of the command as text and not a screenshot. :)

Comment: Sure, "never send id or aws access keys". a golden rule